# How to extract substring of a field in mongoDB using mongo template

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate

I have one field "branch" in a mongo collection "Location". Format of branch field is something like this "India.Delhi.Saket" or sometimes "India.Punjab". I want to extract 2nd value from each of the record and get count them by using mongo template.

```
Ex.

|branch                 | branch_substring(Intermediate value)|
|-----------------------|-------------------------------------|
| India.Delhi.Saket     |      Delhi                          |
| India.Punjab          |      Punjab                         |
| India.Delhi           |      Delhi                          |

This should give output as follows

|branch |count|
|-------|-----|
|Delhi  | 2   |
|Punjab | 1   |
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `$project`: Produce document with `country_branch` (array) field. The [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) operator splits `branch` string to a string array, using "." as separator.
2. `$group`: Group all documents with the second element of `country_branch` (`$arrayElementAt`) and perform `$count`.
3. `$sort`: Sort `count` by descending.
4. `$project`: Project document with `branch` and `count` fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "country_branch": {
        "$split": [
          "$branch",
          "."
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "branch": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$country_branch",
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      "count": {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "count": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "branch": "$_id.branch",
      "count": "$count"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7qHlt19ST9R)

> Output

```
[
  {
    "branch": "Delhi",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "branch": "Punjab",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```